# Why is "plumbing" used, and what does "new lows" mean?

Tags: meaning, grammar, sentence, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> At the start of the year unemployment was plumbing new lows.

Can you explain why **"plumbing"** is used and what **"new lows"** means?

Comment: Bad sentence there. Plumbing new lows -> reaching new depths. It'll confuse people as to whether unemployment had reached record lows, or record highs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to understand the nautical connotation.  A sailor would "plumb the depths" of a harbor using a cord with a lead (plumbum) weight on the end of it.  In fact, this is where Mark Twain got his moniker.

So, "plumbing new lows" means going "deeper" than previously (in recent history) seen.

(And I'll note that "plumbing" in the sense of pipes gets its name from the common use of lead pipes in prior eras.)

Answer (score -2):

"plumbing" is a sort of measurement.

The rates of unemployment got the lowest points
at various jobs. 
That is, the employment rates climbed onto the highest peaks at various fields.